# Using GCP Cloud SQL SocketFactory with Hibernate Configuration

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, google-cloud-sql, socketfactory

I am trying to connect to a Cloud SQL Postgres Database instance from GCP App Engine (GAE) Standard.  Using the database instance connection name (my-project-id:europe-west1:db-instance-name) with the Cloud SQL SocketFactory with Hibernate.

```
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

                // Hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml's properties
                Properties settings = new Properties();

                settings.put("hibernate.connection.provider_class","com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory");

                settings.put("hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle","5");
                settings.put("hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize","10");
                settings.put("hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout","30000");
                 settings.put("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url","jdbc:postgres://google/database-name?cloudSqlInstance=project:europe-west1:instance-id&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory");
                settings.put("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user","postgres");
                settings.put("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password","password");                    


                      settings.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Country.class);

                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.info("============EXCEPTION===========>"+e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
```

Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the implementation you’re using isn’t fit for App Engine Standard, you should check the Google implementation that can be found on the official documentation.

[Official Google documentation to connect to CloudSQL from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine)

[Google example project on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/postgres/servlet/src/main/java/com/example/cloudsql/ConnectionPoolContextListener.java)